# class not found since enable_lazy_ghost_objects is activated

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Symfony 6.4
Doctrine/orm 2.17

I saw this deprecation

```
Since doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.11: Not setting "enable_lazy_ghost_objects" to true is deprecated
```

in the doctrine config file, i added this line :

```
    orm:
        enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true
```

Since i did that, a have a lot of error while running commands since my crontab
Example :

```
In LazyObjectRegistry.php line 70:
  [ErrorException]
  Warning: Class "arreteCompte" not found

Exception trace:
  at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/var-exporter/Internal/LazyObjectRegistry.php:70
 Symfony\Component\VarExporter\Internal\LazyObjectRegistry::getClassResetters() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/var-exporter/LazyGhostTrait.php:52
 Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Bail::createLazyGhost() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php:471
 Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Bail::Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php:212
 Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory->getProxy() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:3050
 Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->createEntity() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php:272
 Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->getEntity() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php:498
 Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->hydrateRowData() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php:149
 Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->hydrateAllData() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php:270
 Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator->hydrateAll() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php:1225
 Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->executeIgnoreQueryCache() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php:1166
```

The error occured when I enter in this loop :

```
$assuranceBaux = $this->assuranceBailRepository->findAssuranceBailNeeded();

foreach ($assuranceBaux as $assuranceBail) {
    ...
}
```

in the repository, i have something like this :
public function findAssuranceBailNeeded()
{
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ab');

```
    return $qb->select('ab')
        ->join('ab.typeAssurance', 'at')
        ->join(
            'ab.bail',
            'b',
            Join::WITH,
            $qb->expr()->orX(
                ...
            )
        )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

AssuranceBail entity :

```
class AssuranceBail
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'SEQUENCE')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Bail::class, inversedBy: 'assurances')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private $bail;

    ...
```

Bail entity :

```
class Bail
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'SEQUENCE')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(mappedBy: 'bail', targetEntity: ArreteCompte::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[Groups(['detailRestitDg', 'listDg', 'detailRestitDg', 'informationsDg'])]
    private ?ArreteCompte $arreteCompte;
```

When i look the doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppEntityBail.php file, i have this :

```
namespace Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity;

/**
 * DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - IT WAS CREATED BY DOCTRINE'S PROXY GENERATOR
 */
class Bail extends \App\Entity\Bail implements \Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\InternalProxy
{
    use \Symfony\Component\VarExporter\LazyGhostTrait {
        initializeLazyObject as __load;
        setLazyObjectAsInitialized as public __setInitialized;
        isLazyObjectInitialized as private;
        createLazyGhost as private;
        resetLazyObject as private;
    }

    private const LAZY_OBJECT_PROPERTY_SCOPES = [
        ...
        "\0".parent::class."\0".'arreteCompte' => [parent::class, 'arreteCompte', 'arreteCompte'],
```

Even if i had join on the ArreteCompte table in the repository, I have the same error.
I don't understand what doctrine needs, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue. However, when changing auto_generate_proxy_classes: true to false, the problem seems to be resolved for me. How is it configured on your end?

Comment: Same experience as you, setting auto_generate_proxy_classes to false solved the problem. i had this parameter to "true" in the dev environment but now i changed it to false also